# Python Polars: Calculate time difference from first element in each (repeating) group

Tags: python, datetime, group-by, python-polars, timedelta

I have a `polars.DataFrame` like:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
"timestamp": ['2009-04-18 11:30:00', '2009-04-18 11:40:00', '2009-04-18 11:50:00', '2009-04-18 12:00:00', '2009-04-18 12:10:00', '2009-04-18 12:20:00', '2009-04-18 12:30:00'],
"group": ["group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_2", "group_2", "group_1", "group_1"]})

df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("timestamp").str.to_datetime().dt.replace_time_zone("UTC"),
)

┌─────────────────────────┬─────────┐
│ timestamp               ┆ group   │
│ ---                     ┆ ---     │
│ datetime[μs, UTC]       ┆ str     │
╞═════════════════════════╪═════════╡
│ 2009-04-18 11:30:00 UTC ┆ group_1 │
│ 2009-04-18 11:40:00 UTC ┆ group_1 │
│ 2009-04-18 11:50:00 UTC ┆ group_1 │
│ 2009-04-18 12:00:00 UTC ┆ group_2 │
│ 2009-04-18 12:10:00 UTC ┆ group_2 │
│ 2009-04-18 12:20:00 UTC ┆ group_1 │ <- reappearance of group_1
│ 2009-04-18 12:30:00 UTC ┆ group_1 │ <- reappearance of group_1
└─────────────────────────┴─────────┘
```

I want to calculate the time difference between the timestamp of the first element in each group to the timestamp of the elements in a group. **Important is, that 'group' is defined as a (chronologically) consecutive appearance of the same group label. Like in the example shown group labels can occur later in time with the same group label but should by then be treated as a new group.**

With that, the result should look something like this:

```
┌─────────────────────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ timestamp               ┆ group   │ timediff│
│ ---                     ┆ ---     │ ---     │
│ datetime[μs, UTC]       ┆ str     │ int(?)  │
╞═════════════════════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 2009-04-18 11:30:00 UTC ┆ group_1 │ 0       │
│ 2009-04-18 11:40:00 UTC ┆ group_1 │ 10      │
│ 2009-04-18 11:50:00 UTC ┆ group_1 │ 20      │
│ 2009-04-18 12:00:00 UTC ┆ group_2 │ 0       │
│ 2009-04-18 12:10:00 UTC ┆ group_2 │ 10      │
│ 2009-04-18 12:20:00 UTC ┆ group_1 │ 0       │ <- reappearance of group_1
│ 2009-04-18 12:30:00 UTC ┆ group_1 │ 10      │ <- reappearance of group_1
└─────────────────────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.rle_id()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rle_id.html) ("Run-length encoding") can be used to identify the groups.

> This is especially useful when you want to define groups by runs of identical values

```py
df.with_columns(group_id = pl.col("group").rle_id())
```

```
shape: (7, 3)
┌─────────────────────────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ timestamp               ┆ group   ┆ group_id │
│ ---                     ┆ ---     ┆ ---      │
│ datetime[μs, UTC]       ┆ str     ┆ u32      │
╞═════════════════════════╪═════════╪══════════╡
│ 2009-04-18 11:30:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 0        │
│ 2009-04-18 11:40:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 0        │
│ 2009-04-18 11:50:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 0        │
│ 2009-04-18 12:00:00 UTC ┆ group_2 ┆ 1        │
│ 2009-04-18 12:10:00 UTC ┆ group_2 ┆ 1        │
│ 2009-04-18 12:20:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 2        │
│ 2009-04-18 12:30:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 2        │
└─────────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────┘
```

You can then run the calculation `.over()` each group.

```py
df.with_columns(timediff =
   (pl.col("timestamp") - pl.col("timestamp").first())
   .over(pl.col("group").rle_id())
   #.dt.minutes()
)
```

```
shape: (7, 3)
┌─────────────────────────┬─────────┬──────────────┐
│ timestamp               ┆ group   ┆ timediff     │
│ ---                     ┆ ---     ┆ ---          │
│ datetime[μs, UTC]       ┆ str     ┆ duration[μs] │
╞═════════════════════════╪═════════╪══════════════╡
│ 2009-04-18 11:30:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 0µs          │
│ 2009-04-18 11:40:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 10m          │
│ 2009-04-18 11:50:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 20m          │
│ 2009-04-18 12:00:00 UTC ┆ group_2 ┆ 0µs          │
│ 2009-04-18 12:10:00 UTC ┆ group_2 ┆ 10m          │
│ 2009-04-18 12:20:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 0µs          │
│ 2009-04-18 12:30:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 10m          │
└─────────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: I didn't even know that existed. When did that come about?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor `.rle()` and `.rle_id()` were added in `0.18.7`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, the "reference time" to calculate the time difference is the start of each group. You would not want to group-by since you want the reference time to reset whenever a new set of consecutive group elements starts, even if the group appears before.

You can achieve this with a `shift` and `forward_fill`, see comments in the code:

```py
df = df.with_columns(
    (
        pl.col("timestamp")
        - (
            # where group changes:
            pl.when((pl.col("group").shift() != pl.col("group"))
                    # first element must be true as well
                    .fill_null(True))
            # use timestamp where group changes:
            .then(pl.col("timestamp"))
            # otherwise None...
            .otherwise(None)
            # ...which is filled with the reference time (group change):
            .forward_fill()
        )
    ).alias("group_diff")
)
```

```
df
┌─────────────────────────┬─────────┬──────────────┐
│ timestamp               ┆ group   ┆ group_diff   │
│ ---                     ┆ ---     ┆ ---          │
│ datetime[μs, UTC]       ┆ str     ┆ duration[μs] │
╞═════════════════════════╪═════════╪══════════════╡
│ 2009-04-18 11:30:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 0µs          │
│ 2009-04-18 11:40:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 10m          │
│ 2009-04-18 11:50:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 20m          │
│ 2009-04-18 12:00:00 UTC ┆ group_2 ┆ 0µs          │
│ 2009-04-18 12:10:00 UTC ┆ group_2 ┆ 10m          │
│ 2009-04-18 12:20:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 0µs          │
│ 2009-04-18 12:30:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 10m          │
└─────────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────────┘
```

If you need the time difference to be just the minutes, you can get that like

```py
df = df.with_columns(
        pl.col("group_diff").dt.minutes().alias("group_diff_minutes")
)
```

See also: [polars.Temporal](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/temporal.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need a way to recategorize the groups so that the first `group_1` is different than the second `group_1`. You can do that by comparing the current group to the prior such that it's True when they're not equal. In that way, you can do a cumulative sum of that which becomes the new group. With that new group definition, you can use a window function to subtract the current timestamp from the first timestamp of the group. Lastly you convert that to minutes.

```
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        timediff=(
            pl.col('timestamp')-
                pl.col('timestamp')
                    .first()
                    .over((pl.col('group')!=pl.col('group').shift().backward_fill()).cumsum())
            ).dt.minutes()
        )
    )
shape: (7, 3)
┌─────────────────────────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ timestamp               ┆ group   ┆ timediff │
│ ---                     ┆ ---     ┆ ---      │
│ datetime[μs, UTC]       ┆ str     ┆ i64      │
╞═════════════════════════╪═════════╪══════════╡
│ 2009-04-18 11:30:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 0        │
│ 2009-04-18 11:40:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 10       │
│ 2009-04-18 11:50:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 20       │
│ 2009-04-18 12:00:00 UTC ┆ group_2 ┆ 0        │
│ 2009-04-18 12:10:00 UTC ┆ group_2 ┆ 10       │
│ 2009-04-18 12:20:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 0        │
│ 2009-04-18 12:30:00 UTC ┆ group_1 ┆ 10       │
└─────────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────┘
```